# Einstein summation convention in deriving Coulomb's law

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory, tensor-calculus, notation

Schwartz's QFT equation (3.43) reads

$$ \mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{4} (\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu)^2 - A_\mu J_\mu. \tag{3.43}$$

Does the contraction of $\mu$ on the last term carry over to the first term? In particular, is it the same as saying:

$$ \mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{4} (\partial_t A_\nu + \partial_x A_\nu + \partial_y A_\nu + \partial_z A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_t - \partial_\nu A_x - \partial_\nu A_y - \partial_\nu A_z)^2 $$
$$- A_t J_t - A_x J_x - A_y J_y - A_z J_z~? $$

Comment: Does Schwartz *really* write two lower $\mu$’s in the second term? (I hope not, but if so, it makes a difference in explaining what the first term means.)

Comment: Yup Schwartz does. Earlier in the book I think he says he treats lower and upper indices pretty much the same unless he does an explicit calculation

Comment: Does he use $x^4=ict$?

Comment: I don't think so. He uses $x^\mu = (t, x, y, z)$ and $g$ = diag(1, -1, -1, -1) with $\hbar = c = 1$.

Comment: Schwartz treats upper and lower indices the same. Repeated indices include the metric. There is usually no ambiguity in doing this (except for derivatives and for gamma matrices). That's what he does when he teaches his class too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Schwartz’ unfortunate all-indices-are-lower notation, $(\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu)^2$ means $(\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu)(\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu)$. You contract both indices, $\mu$ and $\nu$, to get 16 terms (or 64, depending on what you’re counting as a term).

Contractions in one term of $\mathcal{L}$ (or anywhere else) have nothing to do with contractions in another term. Nothing about contractions “carries over”.

Comment: I guess you fell victim to Schwartz :) If you're using his all-lower convention, you can't just slap summations from 0 to 3, you have to include the explicit metric, otherwise you're missing the minus signs for the space components.

Comment: @Javier Thanks, I removed the summations. I’m glad I never used this convention, although I see its consistency now.